# Can't draw anything but dots in photoshop 6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing

My mouse and wacom only recognizes one touch but anything which require holding like drawing its not working.

Anybody got any ideas?

Cheers!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you use some brush with custom settings? I'd recommend to try to use one of default brushes to check if the problem didn't appear.

Comment: Thx :D but it's not with the brushes, cause not even the box selection tool is working properly, basically everything which requires hold click action.

But it's not with my computer mouse settings either cause in GIMP it works just fine.

Comment: Hmmm... really strange. So it seems that the problem is with your tablet's settings. Try to re-install drivers for your tablet to reset your settings. Depending on settings press+hold can be recognized as custom behaviour like right-click: [link](https://goo.gl/mblA68)